# JQuery function not working as expected

Tags: jquery, css

I've written a little function to position a logo midway between the left hand side of the browser window and the (centered) navigation menu.  The menu items are populated from a database, with the first item given the id item0.

```
function positionLogo(){
    var $menuleft=0;
    var $element=document.getElementById('item0');
    if ($element.offsetParent) {
        do {
            $menuleft+=$element.offsetLeft;
        } while ($element=$element.offsetParent);
    }
    var $logoleft=($menuleft/2)-130; // As logo is 260px wide
    if ($logoleft<0) {
        $logoleft=0;
    }
    $('#logo').css('left',$logoleft);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    positionLogo();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    positionLogo();
});
```

This works fine when the window is resized, but when it first runs when the page is loaded, the position it sets is about 20px too far right (ie $logoleft is 20 more than it should be).  As soon as the page is resized it jumps into the correct position.

Haven't got it live anywhere at the moment but does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I find that [XRAY ](http://www.westciv.com/xray/) works good for debugging things like this.

Comment: Only seems to be a problem in webkit based browsers, and it still does it by 1px even with Nick's fix, but that's good enough for me! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    positionLogo();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    positionLogo();
});
```

With this:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', positionLogo);
```

You need the layout and all sizes to finish up (images loading, etc), so you want the `window.load` method instead of `document.ready`.  Combine that with `bind()` taking space separated events and you can get it down into a simple one-line handler like that.  One other note, no need to wrap only a function in `function() { }`, just put the function name like I have above :)

Comment: Thanks for that, it's still out by 1px for some reason, but I'm not going to complain about that!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried handling `window.onload`? This will fire when the page is completely loaded, rather then when the DOM is ready (like `$(document).ready`)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to repeat the phenomenon. There is some bug in IE that has to do with `offsetParent`, that might have something to do with it depending on how you have positioned the elements. You can use the `offset` method in jQuery to get around the browser incompatiblities there.

For some reason it seems to work even in Firefox without specifying a unit for the `left` style, but it really should have one.

```
function positionLogo(){
   var menuleft = $('#item0').offset().left;
   var logoleft = Math.max(0, (menuleft / 2) - 130); // As logo is 260px wide
   $('#logo').css('left', logoleft + 'px');
}
```

or simply:

```
function positionLogo(){
   $('#logo').css('left', Math.max(0, ($('#item0').offset().left / 2) - 130) + 'px');
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have been specifying a unit.  And I added in a round to avoid trying to position fractions of pixels.  Thanks for the tip about offset as well.

Answer (score 0):

If resizing the window is working then maybe you should try triggering the function with a resize:

so replace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    positionLogo();
});
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```